# Affecting the motion of a div container with another moving div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Sorry for the confusing title. But, you can see [here a JsFiddle **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/66eNh/1/) What I mean.

What I am trying to achieve is to, move the black container as soon as it gets in contact  the red container container. Meaning, I don't want the red container to overlap with the black on, I am trying to move the red, relative to the position of the red on. 
I am probably certain this can be achieve using normal CSS with float/margin/display adjustments, that I am unable to produce now.

Here is the code:

**JavaScript**

```
var speed =80, deg=0, center={x:50,y:50},
        moveBox = function(){
            var el = document.getElementById("circle"),
                left = el.offsetLeft,
                moveBy = 3; 
                deg+=moveBy;
                el.style.left =center.x+Math.floor(40*Math.sin(deg/150*Math.PI))+"px";
                el.style.top =center.y+Math.floor(20*Math.cos(deg/150*Math.PI))+"px";
        };

var timer = setInterval(moveBox, speed);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='square'></div>
<div id='circle'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#circle{background:red; display:inline-block; width:80%; height:40px; position:absolute; border:1px solid #454545; margin-top:100px;}
#square{width:60px; height:50px; background:black; display:block; position:relative; position:absolute; margin-left:100px; margin-top:100px;}
```

Comment: Not as simple as it seems. First off, elements with absolute positioning are taken out of the normal document flow. Also, relative positioning does not affect document flow (their position in the document flow is the same as if they were static). Doing this with CSS would require quite some refactoring from your example.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I guess you are right. I thought the solution would be something simple, I can't bring myself to see. But, I guess I have to wait and see, if someone can come with another alternative,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been toying with this on your Fiddle and it seems very untaskable at the moment.  To fix problems of divs moving when animations are done, you put a relative/absolute css position on them. But when doing that to yours, it breaks the darn Circle.

So, if you can figure out how to make the circle work without a css position like so, then it should work itself out.  Sorry for the lack of finding a simple solution for you.